# Is «plausible» a false friend between English and Spanish?

Tags: english, spanish

I'm a native Spanish speaker and today I was just wondering about this, if it's a case like `bizarre` and `bizarro` (which in Spanish means «generous» or «brave», not «weird»).

I couldn't fully understand what it means in English, so I'd appreciate a native's opinion on this.

Comment: As this is essentially just asking for an English definition (you don't even explain what the Spanish word means), this is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plausible means "believable". It's a false friend, but it has the same etymology. Originally it meant "praiseworthy", as in Spanish, then it was used to refer to a good argument in a debate - a believable one. Eventually the meaning of "believable" supplanted the original meaning.

Comment: ¡Gracias, Charlotte!

Comment: It was, but not anymore.